# How do I repair a cxf-codegen-plugin throwing an error in POM

Tags: apache-camel, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I want to use cxf-codegen-plugin to generate-sources with wsdl2java in my camel maven project.

I added the plugin as follows to my pom.

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.4</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>generate-sources</id>
       <phase>generate-sources</phase>
       <configuration>
         <wsdlOptions>
           <wsdlOption>
             <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/BookService.wsdl</wsdl>
           </wsdlOption>
         </wsdlOptions>
       </configuration>
       <goals>
         <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
```

This throws an error in the pom...

```
Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.4:wsdl2java failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-
 plugin:3.2.4:wsdl2java: javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/HexBinaryAdapter ----------------------------------------------------- realm = plugin>org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-
 plugin:3.2.4 strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy urls[0] = file:/C:/esb/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-codegen-plugin/3.2.4/cxf-codegen-
 plugin-3.2.4.jar urls[1] = file:/C:/esb/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.5/plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar urls[2] = file:/C:/esb/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-
 archiver/1.2/plexus-archiver-1.2.jar ...
```

I tried other example projects like https://github.com/sigreen/camel-cxf-soap-client and got similar errors in the pom Since I am sure it worked back in 2015 when this project was committed, I assume it is a version mismatch today.

If someone has a recent project with cxf-codegen-plugin that would help.

Comment: I even tried to add it to the Camel cxf code first quickstart and even that throws errors ... Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.4:wsdl2java failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-
 plugin:3.2.4:wsdl2java: javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/HexBinaryAdapter

Comment: added two dependencies based on the error stack...<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
     <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
     </dependency>
     <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api -->
     <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
     </dependency>   I added the bookstore.wsdl

Comment: Now the missing files are replaced with errors in the BookService.wsdl ... <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost:50847/BookService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
      The part 'parameters' has an invalid value 'GetBooksList' defined for its element. Element declarations must refer to valid values defined in a schema.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my jdk version from 11 to 8 and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I kept making changes based on details in the error stacks that kept changing with each change.  Here is the final plugin entry in the pom that was clean...

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.ws/jaxws-api -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jws/javax.jws-api -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/BookService.wsdl</wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

for the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- <sourceRoot>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>-->
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>src/main/resources/9874.wsdl
                                    </wsdl>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I used this dependency and it worked well:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>3.17.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```